# How to do data transformation using Apache NiFi standrad processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to do data transfomration using Apache NiFi standard processor for below mentioned input data. I have to add two new fields class and year and drop extra price fields.

Below are my input data and transformed data.

**Input data**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

Comment: This question needs more information to help people answer. I think it's unlikely that a chain of the standard processors will be able to perform the custom logic implied by your input and output (you don't explicitly state the transformation steps). You will probably need a custom processor or custom logic in a script to be run with ExecuteScript.

Comment: @Andy - thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am assuming that your input headers are not dynamic, which means that you can maintain a predictable input schema. If that is true, you can do this with the standard processors as of 1.12.0, but it will require a little work.

[Here's a blog post](https://mikethomsen.github.io/posts/2020/11/19/building-all-new-record-sets-with-scriptedtransformrecord/#building-all-new-record-sets-with-scriptedtransformrecord) of mine about how to use `ScriptedTransformRecord` to take input from one schema, build a new data structure and mix it with another schema. It's a bit involved.

I've used that methodology recently to convert a much larger set of data into summary records, so I know it works. The summary of what's involved is this:

1. Create two schemas, one that matches input and one for output.
2. Set up `ScriptedTransformRecord` to use a writer that explicitly sets which schema to use since `ScriptedTransformRecord` doesn't support the ability to change the schema configuration internally.
3. Create a fat jar with Maven or Gradle that compiles your Avro schema into an object that can be used with the NiFi API to expose a static `RecordSchema` (NiFi API) to your script.
4. Write a Groovy script that generates a new `MapRecord`.